# Correct way of object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

I have a scenario, where I receive an obj from a promise, and need to add some keys of this object to another object. For example:

```
// Received from promise
object_1 = {
    name: 'SH'
};

// Want to add object_1.name to object_2 
object_2 = {
    id: 1234
};
```

Normally I could do like following, but I want to do it with object destructuring

```
object_2.name = object_1.name;
```

to have:

```
object_2 = {
    id: 1234,
    name: 'SH'
};
```

Comment: You might want object spread instead, which requires only one line, unlike destructuring? `const object_2 = { id: 1234, ...object_1 }`

Comment: @CertainPerformance this could be a part of the `module.exports` also where the `object_1` is being exported and then imported in another file.

Comment: There is really no good reason to use destructuring for assigning a single property.

Comment: Whilst @CertainPeformances suggestion in the comment above achieves your desired result given in your question... You need to be mindful that if  `object_1` also has an `id` property, lets say with value of `6789` - then your _object_2_ will be  `{id: 6789, name: "SH"}`. i.e. The  `id` in `object_1` will take precedence over the specified `id: 1234`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to a target object/property with a [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern).

```js
var object_1 = { name: 'SH' },
    object_2 = { id: 1234 };

({ name: object_2.name } = object_1);

console.log(object_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the expected output by using object destructing like this:

```
// Received from promise
object_1 = {
    name: 'SH'
};

// Want to add object_1.name to object_2 
object_2 = {
    id: 1234
};

object_2 = {
  ...object_2,
  ...object_1
}
```

Comment: This is not destructuring at all. You are using object literal spread syntax.

Comment: The answer does the job, but it adds all the properties of object_1.